# "arguments" não funciona numa arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Estou fazendo um teste simples com *arrow function*, mas quando uso o `arguments` ele retorna

> Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined

Como posso usar os parâmetros?

```js
const teste = () => {
  for(i in arguments){
    return arguments[i];
  }
}

teste('teste', 123);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que é isto que deseja, apesar de não fazer muito sentido porque vai imprimir o primeiro e não fará mais nada.

Conforme o erro informava, faltava declarar o `arguments` e dizer que ele seria um *array* de argumentos e não apenas um deles, por isso usei o `...` que é uma construção para isto mesmo.

```js
const teste = (...args) => { for(i in args) return args[i]; }

console.log(teste('teste', 123));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Spread.js).

Talvez queria usar o [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield), mas aí não dá para usar a sintaxe de *arrow function*?

Mudei o nome da variável conforme o comentário do bfavaretto. Ele tem razão que em se tratando do ecossistema do JS é possível que algum conflito ocorra se não hoje, algum dia, já que `arguments` é "mágico".

E de acordo com o comentário do AP não dá para fazer sem declarar porque ele quer uma semântica diferente do que existe "magicamente" com o uso do `arguments`. Sai da convenção criada, é preciso da configuração que sempre é mais verbosa.

Comment: O lance era não passar o (...arguments) mesmo, igual que fosse uma função normal. Mas vi que que as funções arrow não criam isso.

Comment: Obrigado, Maniero!

Comment: Acho que seria mais prudente usar `...args` em vez de `arguments`. Não é palavra reservada, mas imagino que possa dar problema em alguns casos. Talvez se transpilado para o ES5, se o transpilador não tomar certos cuidados.

Comment: @bfavaretto de fato, mudado.